# How to export selected columns using Aggrid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to export aggrid data to Excel. But i want to export selected columns only. I didn't find any option to exclude columns while export.

Can anyone suggest how to export selected columns only.

Comment: Can anyone suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define specific columns using the `columnKeys` parameter in `exportDataAsExcel()`.

See the documentation here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/excel-export-api/#excelexportparams

Answer (score 0):

Using 'columnKeys' in the params is the correct way to do this. For example you can grab your column field names and pass them in: In this example my field names are 'employeeNumber', 'firstLastName', and 'currentlyRequestedHours' which I grab from my columnDefs.

```
  {
    field: 'employeeNumber',
    headerName: 'ID',
    filter: 'text',
    sortable: true,
    filterParams: { suppressAndOrCondition: true },
  },
  {
    autoHeight: true,
    field: 'firstLastName',
    headerName: 'Name',
    sortable: true,
    filter: 'text',
    filterParams: { suppressAndOrCondition: true },
  },
  {
    field: 'currentlyRequestedHours',
    headerName: 'Pending Hours',
    sortable: true,
    valueFormatter: gridDateValueFormatter,
    filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
    filterParams: { suppressAndOrCondition: true },
    type: 'numericColumn',
  }...

  private params = {
     columnKeys: ['employeeNumber', 'firstLastName', 'currentlyRequestedHours']
  };

  onBtExport() {
     this.gridApi?.exportDataAsExcel(this.params);
  }
```